# Yii2 authTimeout is not working

Tags: yii2

The login `authTimeout` is set to two hours but the system logout itself after 30 minutes if the system is idle. Any idea why that happened?

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout' => 7200,
        'enableSession' => true,
    ],
]
```

Comment: check for php session duration  ..

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is related to session timeout. Usual default value is about ~30 minutes, so session will expire before `authTimeout` takes effect. You need to adjust [`Session::$timeout`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session#$timeout-detail) value in your config:

```
'session' => [
    'timeout' => 7200, // or greater
],
```